# Nginx conf for prerender + reverse proxy to django + serving angular in html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, nginx, pushstate, prerender

The mouthful of a title says it all:

We've got an Angular frontend with a Django backend providing a REST API that is exposed independently at endpoints `example.com/api/v1/*`

The Angular app runs in HTML5 mode, and we want hard-links to `example.com/foo/bar` to bring users into the app at the `foo.bar` state as if it were a static page rather than an app state (where `foo` is anything but `api`).

We're running behind nginx,and our basic strategy in the conf was to  define locations at `^~ /scripts`, `/images` etc. for serving static content directly, as well as a `^~ /api/*` location that gets routed to django. Below that, we have a `location ~ ^/.+$` that matches any path not matched by any of the above and "sends it to Angular" - i.e. serves our index page to it and appends the path to the base url, allowing our angular router to handle it from there.

This is our conf in full:

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen          443;
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/thawte/example_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/thawte/example_com.key;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/html application/javascript application/json;
    gzip_proxied        any; 

    index index.html;

    location ^~ /index.html {
        gzip_static on;
        root /www/dist;
    }
    location ^~ /images/ {
        expires max;
        root /www/dist;
    }
    location ^~ /scripts/ {
        expires max;
        gzip_static on;
        root /www/dist;
    }

    location ^~ /favicon.ico {
        expires max;
        root /www/dist;
    }

    location ^~ /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    //Send anything else to angular 
    location ~ ^/.+$ {
        rewrite .* /index.html last;
    }
```

}

This has worked perfectly for us, **but we now need to set it up to work with prerender.io**. We've tried doing this several ways, making modifications on [the official prerender nginx example](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802), but none have worked - crawlers are getting the same code users are rather than cached pages.

**How can we get this working?**

(note: this is new territory for everyone involved here, so if the best way to handle this involves making different choices a few steps back, please suggest them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the config posted above was working the whole time.

I realized this when it finally occurred to me to try putting `https://example.com/anything` through the crawler debugger (instead of `https://example.com`, which is all I had been testing previously), and it worked - the crawler was served the cached page as expected.

This was simply because the greedy quantifier in:

```
location ~ ^/.+$ {
```

did not match the empty string. With an additional

```
location = / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
 }
```

, my conf is working as expected.

Hopefully the handprint on my forehead d only been putting https://example.com through the crawler debugger - which was not working.

On the upside, I'm thinking I can turn this handprint on my forehead into a nice Halloween costume next weekend....

Still not sure I've gone about this the best way, and welcome alternative suggestions.